# Implicitly cast a generic type to a non-generic equivalent

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, .net-2.0

Given the following classes:

```
public abstract class MyRecordClass
{
    public int id { get; private set; }
}

public class ExampleMyRecordClass : MyRecordClass {}

public enum SomeIntEnum : int {}

public class MyList<T, E> : IList<T>
where T : MyRecordClass
{

}

public class MyOtherClass
{
    public void MyMethod(MyList<T, E> list) {}
}
```

, I'd like call the method like this:

```
MyList<ExampleMyRecordClass, SomeIntEnum> myList;
MyOtherClass myOtherClass;

myOtherClass.MyMethod(myList);
```

However, this won't actually work if passing a list of type `MyList<ExampleMyRecordClass, SomeIntEnum>`, since implicit upcasts don't work in generic types. Since all I really want is the property `id`, I can, of course, explicitly implement a property or method in `MyList<T, E>` that returns a new collection with this information.

What I'd prefer to do is have this done implicitly. Is there a way (an implicit operator, perhaps, or an additional interface to implement in `MyList<T, E>`) to make this possible?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for, but if you make the following change it compiles and runs just fine:

```
public class MyOtherClass
{
    public void MyMethod<T, E>(MyList<T, E> list) where T : MyRecordClass { }
}
```

---

Are you perhaps looking for [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)?

```
public class MyList<T, E> : IList<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>
    where T : MyRecordClass
{
}

public class MyOtherClass
{
    public void MyMethod(IReadOnlyList<MyRecordClass> list) { }
}
```

*Usage:*

```
MyList<ExampleMyRecordClass, SomeIntEnum> myList;
MyOtherClass myOtherClass;

myOtherClass.MyMethod(myList);
```

*[IReadOnlyList<T> Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):*

```
public interface IReadOnlyList<out T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    int Count { get; }
    T this[int index] { get; }
}
```